# Finding $P(X>Y)$ where $X\sim U(0,2)$ and $Y\sim U(1,3)$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I have the following problem:

> Two stochastic variables $X\sim U(0,2)$ and $Y\sim U(1,3)$ are independent. What is $P(X>Y)$?

The answers is $\frac18$, but I don't know how to solve.

I did the following:

- I drew both distributions in one plot with height 1/2 --> (1/(2-0))

I see that the distributions have a overlap on interval $[1,2]$, so if $X$ is going to be bigger than $Y$, its going to be in that interval. So I know that the probability of $X$ being in that interval is $(2-1)\times\frac12 = 0.5$.

I don't know how to proceed. Can I have some feedback?

Ter

Comment: Draw the picture.  The joint distribution is uniform on a rectangle and the desired region is a right triangle at one corner of that rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented a picture is a good idea here.

If you want a proof that does not depend on a picture then the following might help.

---

For independent $X,Y$ where $Y$ has a PDF we have the
equalities:

$$P\left(X>Y\right)=\int P\left(X>Y\mid Y=y\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dy=\int P\left(X>y\mid Y=y\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dy=$$$$\int P\left(X>y\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dy$$

Here the last equality rests on independence.

Comment: did you write the middle equality twice ?

Comment: @badatmath There is a slight difference. $P(X>Y\mid Y=y)$ in the first is changed into $P(X>y\mid Y=y)$. So *random variable* $Y$ is changed into *real number* $y$. This is allowed because $P(X>Y\mid Y=y)=P(X>y\mid Y=y)$. After that it is evident that we can write the RHS also as $P(X>y)$ on base of independence of the events $\{X>y\}$ and $\{Y=y\}$. For this we need the step in between because the events $\{X>Y\}$ and $\{Y=y\}$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

As you noted, The only hope for $X>Y$ is for $X$ and $Y$ both to be in $[1,2]$. This happens with probability $\frac14$ (since $X$ and $Y$ are independent).  And then within this $\frac14$ probability, half the time we'll have $X>Y$, and the other half $Y>X$ (noting that $P(X=Y) = 0$).

So $P(X>Y)$ is half of $\frac14$, which is $\frac18$.